# Magento Multi-store Products not Displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, category-tree

I have setup two store fronts in Magento as domain1.com and domain2.com.  Everything seems to be set up properly as changing the domains will display both different themes and different categories as specified in the backend.

However, my second root category for domain2.com does not display any products in it in both the front end and back end. The secondary root is set active and also as anchor. It contains two subcategories which display fine on store front except for the fact that the products I have placed in them are not displaying.

In the backend when editing the categories I can fill both root categories with products. But if I select the secondary store front from the View drop down, I am unable to add any products into this category.  Only when all store views is selected can I see any products in the backend.

Has anyone experienced this issue before or have an idea as to where my configuration may be wrong?

Thanks

Update: Even changing the root category of the secondary store to the original root category still displays no products while the original domain displays fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding multiple stores also added new tabs on the products to select which websites they display in. So adding the root category is not enough, each product must also be assigned to the website that you would like to be displayed.